# Is the .ASPX extension ONLY associated with Web Forms?

Tags: asp.net, webforms

Dumb question (maybe) I have searched online but I'm looking for somewhat a yes no type of answer. If you ever see a website with just xxx.com/xxx.aspx ... was that application created using Web Forms? Is ASPX only associated with Web Forms?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To answer your question in yes or no (as asked), NO.

You can do that in ASP.NET MVC as well, by setting up the routing in that fashion. But I don't think anybody would do that.

On another note, if you have come across a website which is xxx.com/xxx.aspx, you can make a decently good bet that it was developed in ASP.NET WebForms.

Hope that helps!!!

Answer (score 1):

Technically no. The web server software determines how to handle every request. It could be configured pretty easily to say that any requests for a file with a .aspx extension should be handled by the PHP parser, or Ruby, or whatever. Or, if using ASP.NET MVC, you could set up routes that resources that end in .aspx are still handled as MVC pages.

Of course, there aren't many reasons that someone would WANT to do that. The only reason I can think to do so would be if you're explicitly trying to make people think that a page is using a different technology than it is. And I don't see that being a common goal.

Comment: Some sites are a hybrid of Web Forms and MVC. You see that sometimes when they decided to transition their app slowly to MVC instead of all at once.

Comment: Ok. Thanks a lot! I see sites with that extension and they look very good. I had heard that Web Forms were outdated and that the most robust of applications are being developed in MVC. Is this entirely true to an extent? Or can you make modern, robust, beautiful web applications with web forms? I know of reasons why you wouldn't want to use them and just use MVC but I'm wondering if it's still capable.

Comment: You can certainly make modern robust applications with web forms. As far as the capabilities of the final product, there's really no difference between Web Forms and MVC (or really any other current platform for making web apps).

The benefits you get from MVC are that it's much easier to make projects that are maintainable and flexible. You might also get some performance benefits by keeping a solid separation of concerns.

However, even those are just things that are EASIER to get by following an MVC pattern. A really well designed Web Forms project can certainly achieve them too.

Comment: I came across this a little late you could say but thanks for answering!